# Can a chess player promote all pawns to queens?

Tags: chess

In standard chess rules, a pawn is promoted if it reaches the far side of the board. Usually, the pawn's owner chooses to promote it to a queen.

Is it possible for one player to eventually promote all their pawns to queens, in a legal game of chess? Assume the opposing player plays "perfectly badly" to allow this. However, if the game reaches checkmate, it must stop.

Comment: Bonus: is it possible if both players have 9 Queens?

Comment: That seems like it's worth a question in its own right - I'll pose it later unless you want to, William.

Comment: @WilliamNathanael, the answer is yes, it's possible. One question dough, should all the promoted queens remain on the board? If not it's even easier.

Comment: Related: [Find the shortest chess game with 18 queens?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/3540/34836)

Comment: On a side note, this doesn't just require perfectly bad play from the opponent - by normal chess rules whites's play is also pretty bad.

Comment: @Lolgast It actually seems like white's play is pretty good, in the sense that if you opponent is going to allow you to queen 8 pawns you should take the opportunity to do so, and then checkmate easily once you have them.

Comment: @jwg Well, by chess standards, missing 26 mate-in-ones, 4 mate-in-twos and one each of a mate-in-three, -seven, -eight and -nine would be considered pretty bad. In fact, there are only 6 positions in which the lichess analyzer (stockfish, depth 25) doesn't have a mate ready, including  the starting position. Additionally, two of those 6 have a plus score of about 25.

Comment: Well I was about to ask exactly the same puzzle, but then saw this one. Good to know.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[This 40 move solution on lichess](https://lichess.org/W6YBhwPd) works, and while it may not be the most orderly solution, it is impossible to create a solution in fewer moves since I'm using optimal pawn movement at every step and no other pieces (6 fields to move, 2 in the initial move, so 5 moves for each pawn to promote).

PGN of the game:

```
1. e4 f5 2. exf5 Kf7 3. f6 Nh6 4. fxe7 Kg8 5. e8=Q Ng4 6. f4 h6 7. f5 Kh7
8. f6 Qe7+ 9. fxe7 Nc6 10. exf8=Q Nge5 11. g4 Nf7 12. g5 Kg6 13. gxh6 Kf5
14. hxg7 Nb4 15. g8=Q Rh5 16. h4 Rg5 17. h5 Nc6 18. h6 Nb4 19. h7 Nc6
20. h8=Q Nb4 21. d4 Nc6 22. d5 b5 23. dxc6 Bb7 24. cxd7 Bd5 25. d8=Q Be6
26. c4 Rh5 27. cxb5 Rg5 28. b6 Rh5 29. bxc7 Rb8 30. c8=Q Rb5 31. a4 Rg5
32. axb5 Rh5 33. b6 Rg5 34. bxa7 Rh5 35. a8=Q Rg5 36. b4 Rh5 37. b5 Rg5
38. b6 Rh5 39. b7 Rg5 40. b8=Q
```

GIF:

[image: 40 move solution]

Comment: I think the chess animations might only be on the [Chess Stack Exchange](https://chess.stackexchange.com/) itself

Comment: @phflack  chess.se has a replayer, but I wouldn't call it an animation.

Comment: Perhaps chess.se has a separate replayer, but I've seen other posts on puzzling with just a gif, so that should work

Comment: @HerbWolfe I wouldn't, either. But it's much better than an animation, since it allows the reader to move backwards and forwards through the game at their own pace.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Absolutely it's better than the animated .gifs. I personally find them to be annoying.